# How can I save the date in Excel?

Tags: python, excel, typeerror

```
import datetime
from openpyxl import Workbook


now = datetime.datetime.now()
nowDate = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
#print(nowDate)


wb = Workbook()
sheet1 = wb.active
sheet1.title = 'sampleSheet'

sheet1.cell(row=nowDate, column=1).value = nowDate

wb.save(filename='test.xlsx')
```

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

How can I save the date in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem is with `row = nowDate`


Now row is expecting an integer, and you give it a string (date).
If you really want your row to be the date, you could perhaps get rid of the hyphens in the date(10-12-2020) and then join the list elements to get a string, which you convert to an int to get 10122020. That can be achieved like so:

`row=int("".join(nowDate.split('-')))`

So your final code would look like:

```
sheet1.cell(row=int("".join(nowDate.split('-'))), column=1).value = nowDate
```